# Difference between List<T> and List<? extends T>

Tags: java, templates

What is the difference between `List<T>` and `List<? extends T>`? I have read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html but it is still not clear to me.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate with that question at all.

Comment: I can't answer, so I will comment what I think is the real answer to my question: List<T> represents a List of T elements (each element can be a T or any subclass of T). List<? extends T> represents a List<U> where U extends T. That means you can't add a 'T' element to a List<? extends T> (because it could be a List<U> such that U extends T but the generic T you are trying to add to the list is not of type U) but you can always add a 'T' element to a List<T>. (There are other differences)